# Where are the external Pinax (Starter) Projects?

Tags: python, django, pinax

I've just installed Pinax, and wanted to try some of the external starter projects (as opposed to the four basic ones provided with Pinax). Their documentation links to [this page](http://pinaxproject.com/ecosystem/starter_projects/), but instead of showing a list of external projects, it just links back to that same page.

So my question is, until they fix their documentation, where can I find a list of external Pinax projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're in the process of rewriting them for the fresh-started Pinax 0.9a2. As we do that, they'll appear at http://pinaxproject.com/ecosystem/starter_projects/ but no external ones have been upgraded yet. You can find the old ones on the master-old branch of https://github.com/pinax/pinax though.

Comment: The link still seems to be dead, or at least non-sensical, in that it links back to its own page, but provides no way to access any starter projects

Answer (score 0):

You can find some on Pinax GitHub page: http://github.com/pinax

Here are a couple:
https://github.com/pinax/pinax-symposion-project
https://github.com/pinax/pinax-multiblog-project

Comment: Yeah, I found that eventually, but it's still not even near to all the external projects that I know existed a year ago.

Comment: @HermanSchaaf well, no external projects existed a year ago. They were all internal.

Comment: @JamesTauber True, but what I mean is "what would now be external" :)

Comment: Herman: the projects your are talking about aren't compatible with current Pinax version.